# MFC, long computing in main thread by design, how do you update UI?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, progress-bar

So I have a main thread (C#, UI thread) that spawns a RPC thread (C++)which is my thread that does the long computation via socket read/write. The RPC thread currently creates progress bars to update it while performing the computation(bad design). When I migrated the software to Win7, the status bar would free and I would like to fix that. By design, if I were to change the long computation to a worker thread, it would require a drastic change to the code base which I am not willing to do. On the other hand, I have tried updating UI in a worker thread spawned by the RPC thread, but it went into deadlock situation.

I tried various solutions found online but arrived at no solution.

Does anyone know of a good solution in which I can create UI in the RPC thread without freezing? Thank you

Comment: If the RPC thread is stuck in a blocking call then you can't fix it in that thread. Why not just put the progress bar in the main thread?

Comment: the main thread is in C# (another project). and the socket operation is done via various phases that only the COM object is aware of its state.